# Exponential distribution - lack of memory

Tags: probability, probability-theory

I'm having some problems understanding the concept of lack of memory. Given the following problem:

There are two people at a counter, the time it takes to serve a customer is exponentially distributed with an expected value of $\frac{1}{\lambda}$. Two customers are currently being served and you are next in line. What is the probability that you are not the last one being served?

Now the answer is supposed to be $P = 0.5$. The reasoning goes as follows: Since you will be served only after one customer leaves the counter and the exponential distribution is memoryless, your service time has the same distribution as that of the other customer still being served. Therefore the probability is 0.5.

Now another exercise asked to calculate the probability of waiting 15 minutes given that you have been waiting for 10 minutes already. The waiting time again being exp. distributed,  in this case the probability was equal to that of waiting 5 minutes, i.e.:

$$P(X>15|X>10)=P(X>5)$$

I know that this is what the definition of lack of memory says and it kind of makes sense, I just don't see how this definition does not cause probability of the waiting time of the customer still being served, in the former problem, being less that ones own waiting time to be higher than 0.5. Can anybody please explain this?

Answer (score 0):

If $X,Y$ are independent and exponentially distributed with mean $\frac1\lambda$, then $\mathbb P(X<Y)=\frac{\lambda}{\lambda + \lambda}=\frac12$. The time it takes to serve the remaining customer and the time it takes to serve you both have this distribution.